# Delete or Empty a specific FormControl in a FormArray Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to empty or delete a specific FormControl in a FormArray

'ads' is the FormArray containing FormControl 'ad' and 'id'. And I would like to delete only the 'ad' FormControl

I wrote this code, but it empty the FormArray 'ads' and not the FormControl 'ad' as I was expecting.

```js
onRemoveItem(item: FormGroup) {
  const value = ((item.get('ads')) as FormArray);
  value.removeAt((item.get(['ads', index]) as FormControl).value.ad);
}
```

The 'item' looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove 'ad' FormControl which is inside of 'ads' FormArray and keep the FormControl 'id'

**There is the template:**

```
<div formArrayName="ads">
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let adsCtrl of findFieldChildArray(adCtrl, 'ads').controls; let adIndex=index" (ionDrag)="drag($event, adCtrl, adIndex)">
      <div [formGroupName]="adIndex"> 
      <ion-item>
        <ion-textarea rows="3" type="text" placeholder="Add a description ..." formControlName="ad">
        </ion-textarea>
      </ion-item>

      <!-- ADS remove Button -->
      <ion-item-options side="start">
        <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="onRemoveItem(adCtrl, adIndex)">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="remove-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item-option>
      </ion-item-options>
    </div>
    </ion-item-sliding>

    <!-- Add ADS Button -->
    <ion-button expand="block" color="success" type="button" (click)="onAddNewItem(adCtrl)">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
</div>
```

Thank you to help me to understand what I did wrong

Comment: Show how you construct the form group and its form array, and tell us what you want to remove.

Comment: Please read the docs [removeControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#removeControl)

Comment: Can you please show us how you initialized form?

Comment: `(item.get(['ads', 0]) as FormGroup).removeControl('ad')`

Comment: @JBNizet and Amit Chigadani      I did like this ```  onRemoveItem(item: FormGroup, index: number) { (item.get(['ads', index]) as FormGroup).removeControl('ad'); }``` But it does not delete it on the template :( and i don't know why

Comment: And yet you have the code of the template, but we don't. So how could we know. Do you have anything in the template that makes sure that the control is displayed **only if it exists in the form group**?

Comment: You need remove the control of all elements in the formarray

Comment: @Eliseo I don't want that if not I will lose the elements 'id'

Answer (score -1):

Remove only one input row from FormArray. Please try this.

```
onRemoveItem(idx: number) {
    const items = item.get('ads') as FormArray;
    items.controls.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

Comment: You want to reset the ad value right?
`const items = item.get('ads') as FormArray;`
`const item = items.controls[idx];`
`item.controls['ad'].setValue('');`